# How to get $HOME directory of user in bash script root mode?

Tags: linux, bash

file name **test.sh**

```
echo $HOME
```

running in root privilege -> ***sudo test.sh***

expected

```
/home/username/
```

but getting

```
/root
```

Comment: `getent passwd "$SUDO_USER"` will get you the full set of login info, *including* the home directory. That said, you can also configure which variables `sudo` changes and which it leaves alone, so it's possible to adjust this by changing nothing except the configuration of `/etc/sudoers`. (Such configuration wouldn't be on-topic here, though, system administration being more a matter for our sister site [unix.se]).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, is this one of rare cases we can safely use eval, like `eval "home=~$SUDO_USER"`, instead of parsing the output of getent ?

Comment: It's a little safer to `printf -v cmd 'HOME=~%q' "$SUDO_USER"; eval "$cmd"`, just to be paranoid. That way if even your `SUDO_USER` has been tampered with we still aren't executing arbitrary code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sudo` runs the script as the root-user
To get the name of the user who initiated sudo you can call `echo $SUDO_USER`

To get its home directory:

```
getent passwd $SUDO_USER | cut -d: -f6
```

Comment: can i store this value in a variable?

Comment: `home="$(getent passwd $SUDO_USER | cut -d: -f6)"`

Comment: Using ${SUDO_USER} is not universal. e.g.  Try `sudo -i` twice. `echo "${SUDO_USER}"` will get `root`. `$(loguser)` will do the same.  I think echo "~<username>" is the only sort of universal and portable means, but that does rely on you knowing the username in the first place.  See my answer below for a way that does not need any prior knowledge.

Comment: But then it really depends on what exactly you mean. The answer to "which user initiated this privileged session" is certainly `root` in your example. Conversely, in the general case, there is no guarantee that the privileged session was not simply initiated with a `root` login, and not from an unprivileged account with `sudo` or `su` or etc.

Answer (score 1):

Surely the best way is simply:

```
echo ~username
```

For assignment, tilde must not be quoted:

```
username_home=~username
```

but may be combined with quoted strings, e.g.:

```
new_path=~username/"${another_variable}"
new_paths_array=(~username/"${yet_another}"/*)
```

There may be some subtle things to do with `$HOME` and `~`, especially in relation to `sudo`.

Refer to the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01) regarding tilde expansion. For bash, also see [bash tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html).

Comment: This is simply the easiest way `echo ~`, thanks

Comment: The OP problem is that tilde resolves to the privileged user's home, e.g. /root whereas ~username resolves to, e.g. /home/username . If not using sudo, you are correct

Answer (score 1):

#### Why?

I had a need to know the true login of the user and realised that no method I could find was universal. So I wrote a script. Decided to post it here as this question (out of the dozens of identical ones) was where I gave up searching.

#### Improvement?

This does illustrate a point that the only ***semi reliable*** method I am aware of is the shell expansion of `~`. And even that won't work if there is no shell to expand `~` into.

#### Others are WRONG!

Only kidding :-) not 'wrong' but not universal. Maybe this gets a little closer but I expect it's also not 100% universal, probably far less.

Some people have suggested `${SUDO_USER}`. That is not a universal and portable solution, firstly because [`su`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) exists and secondly because a user may already have used "sudo", see the example below. Others have suggested `$(logname)`, that also breaks in the same way. (So I expect there is a bug in the libc API *)

* The man page for [logname(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logname.1.html) points to [libc(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/libc.7.html) function [getlogin(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getlogin.3.html), which admits it's rubbish.

So I would say this answer is **an** answer but it really depends on what you need. It does contain some nice output formatting though :o)

#### First, illustrate the problem:

```bash
sudo -i
sudo -i
echo "${SUDO_USER}"
# will print "root"
echo "$(logname)"
# will also print "root"
echo "~"
# prints "/root"
echo "~user"
# prints "/home/user"
```

#### Why I needed better:

In researching this I found that unless you know the username before hand there is no easy way to find the true login username and thus the home directory of the current user once they sudo more than once.

Ieeded this on order to provide a script that a user would use to configure their environment when installing a WSL image. But that script would have to run sudo.

Without this, if they did more than one sudo it would break in a very bad way.  I've noticed people copy-paste recipes and often forget to remove the sudo when they should.

#### Solution:

As a resolution to this problem I wrote this script as hopefully a slightly more reliable means of determining the true login username and hence home folder regardless of how that is defined, from passwd/NIS/LDAP/PAM whatever.  The source code for this is in a [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/the-moog/1472aedf0986ded356b1a47a9dd2840f) and under MIT license.

I would not be surprised if there are still edge cases where this also won't work.

#### Method:

Follow the process tree back iteratively, process->parent, Pid->PPid, until we get to `login` or fall off the end with a Pid=1 (usually called `init`).

For a given user, the next thing run after `login` will be run by the UID of that logged in user.
This is usually a shell; e.g. bash, ash, fish, sh, dash, tch; but also could be some sort of non-interactive login using ssh, rsh, rexec or similar.

I think this method will also work in a case where the `~` will not work, i.e. when there is no shell run after login and login just runs a command.  Any shell run after that by some program would lack the immediate parent `login`process so no source of which user was behind it as the environment may not get passed on.

#### Final Selection:

If this script runs it will just get to process 1 - which is always run by root (or boot), how do we detect that it's the user?

- We will select the last found non `UID=0` if that exists or the current `UID`. So that this will also work if the user logs in as root at the beginning.
- We will take the last valid `/proc/<PID>/environ` to find the `${HOME}` variable as that is set by login.  This could also be used to detect the login as before than HOME is meaningless.

NOTE: You will notice that the `login` program is not called login here as this was run on WSL.

#### Edge cases?

I think this would currently break if a root login user sudos to a real user then (assuming that real user has sudo privelages) sudos back. So it would then choose the wrong user, but that would be easy to avoid as we know the initial process after login.
It may also break when tmux or screen are used. (TODO: test that)

```
#!/bin/bash

# get_real_login.sh
# Get the name of the REAL user who is running this script

VERBOSE=1

# Do it lots, use a function
function val () {
echo "$(cat < /dev/stdin)"|tr -d ' \t'|cut -f2 -d:
}

# $$ is the the PID of this script
CPID=$$
# Current user (obviously root)
REAL_UID=$(id -u)
# Fallback HOME
REAL_HOME=/

while [ "${CPID}" -ne 1 ]; do {
 if [ "${CPID}" -ne 1 ]; then
   STAT=$(cat /proc/${CPID}/status)
   CPID_P=$(echo "${STAT}"|grep PPid|val)
   CPN=$(echo "${STAT}"|grep Name|val)
   CPUID=$(echo "${STAT}"|grep Uid)
   CPUID=$(($(echo ${CPUID}|tr -s ' \t' '::'|val)))
   CPUN=$(id -un ${CPUID})
   ENV_HOME=$(cat /proc/${CPID}/environ|tr '\0' '\n'|grep HOME|cut -d= -f2)
   test -n "${VERBOSE}" && {
     echo "CMD:${CPN}";
     echo "PID:${CPID}";
     echo "PPID:${CPID_P}";
     echo "UID:${CPUID}";
     echo "USER:${CPUN}";
   } | printf "%-20.20s %-10.10s %-10.10s %-10.10s %-15.15s\n" $(cat < /dev/stdin)
   if [ ${CPUID} -ne 0 ]; then
     REAL_UID=${CPUID}
   fi
test -n "${ENV_HOME}" && REAL_HOME="${ENV_HOME}"
   CPID="${CPID_P}"
 fi
}; done

REAL_USERNAME=$(id -un ${REAL_UID})
EXISTS=$(test -d $(readlink ${REAL_HOME}) && \
  echo " - EXISTS" || echo " - MISSING !!")
echo -e "\nLogin User: ${REAL_USERNAME} (UID:${REAL_UID}) \${HOME}=\"${REAL_HOME}\"${EXISTS}\n"
```

Before running this I had done a couple `sudo -i` commands to hide my real login.

Interestingly this trace shows sudo creates two processes per sudo, not one!!

#### Output (with VERBOSE=1)

```
root@WSL:~# ./get_real_login.sh
CMD:get_real_lo      PID:31743  PPID:10329 UID:0      USER:root
CMD:bash             PID:10329  PPID:10328 UID:0      USER:root
CMD:sudo             PID:10328  PPID:10320 UID:0      USER:root
CMD:sudo             PID:10320  PPID:10174 UID:0      USER:root
CMD:bash             PID:10174  PPID:10173 UID:0      USER:root
CMD:sudo             PID:10173  PPID:10165 UID:1000   USER:user1000
CMD:sudo             PID:10165  PPID:258   UID:1000   USER:user1000
CMD:bash             PID:258    PPID:255   UID:1000   USER:user1000
CMD:Relay(258)       PID:255    PPID:253   UID:0      USER:root
CMD:SessionLead      PID:253    PPID:2     UID:0      USER:root
CMD:init-system      PID:2      PPID:1     UID:0      USER:root

Login User: user1000 (UID:1000) ${HOME}="/home/user1000" - EXISTS
```